# How to add a fade transition effect to maskview iOS 8?

Tags: ios

I have created UITextView text as a mask for background image in order to color text dynamically with respect to the image behind by using the **maskview** function introduced with iOS 8.

But I want to add a fade effect during the masking operation.

In other words how can I add an transition animation to the masking operation ?

I actually used the code below but fail to integrate the animation in it.

```
self.view.maskView = self.textView
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in an animation block? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the textView alpha to 0.0, set it as the maskView, and then make an animation that sets the alpha to 1.0.

```
self.textView.alpha = 0;
self.view.maskView = self.textView;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            maskView.alpha = 1.0;
        }];
```

Comment: By using this, I can get rid of the flash effect when self.view.maskView = self.textView assignment is done.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` animation property with your view,it will give u fade effect

```
[UIView transitionWithView:"yourView"
                      duration:0.3f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{

                       //animation code
                    } completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have combined two solutions stated here in order to achieve what I am looking for but can't escape the flash effect occurred after the self.view.maskView = self.textView assignment

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.textView, duration: 1.0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromTop, animations: {

        self.view.maskView = self.textView
        self.view.maskView.alpha = 0.0
        self.view.maskView.alpha = 1.0

        }, completion: nil   
    )
```